# How can I reliably stop a tomcat thread in a spring+pdfbox application?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, pdfbox

I have tomcat threads being stuck indefinitely (until tomcat is restarted). My application is built in with spring and the last debug message shows me a call to this method:

```
public byte[] getPageAsImageByteArray(byte[] pdfFileData, double scale) {
    PDFRenderer renderer = null;
    try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(pdfFileData)) {

        renderer = new PDFRenderer(doc);
        BufferedImage img = renderer.renderImage(0, (float) scale);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", baos);
        return baos.toByteArray();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception when rendering page using pdfbox", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This call never returns.

Is there a way for me to rewrite this method to reliably exit after a set timeout?

Comment: What PDFBox version and what jdk are you using? Are you using the KCMS option described in the website? I'm asking because some PDFs can be very slow with some complex files, and no, PDFBox does not have a "graceful" way to quit rendering. If possible, share your PDF.

Comment: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/getting-started.html

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I'm using pdfbox 2.0.8 with java 7. The current "stuck" thread has ben stuck for ~18 hours. I can not share the pdf sorry :) Can this be an issue with render being called with "scale = 0.1" ? I seem to only be running into this when drawing thumbnails.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr The PDF also contains JBIG2 images, and I'm using the jbig2-imageio 3.0.0 dependency.

Comment: jdk7 then the KCMS thing doesn't apply. But each PDFBox version is better than the previous one, so please try 2.0.9, and use `PDFRenderer.setSubsamplingAllowed(true)` this is new and should speed up low resolutions. We've not had compaints about very low scales... maybe try some PDFs that you can share? Or try with the PDF files found in the ZIP files here: http://downloads.digitalcorpora.org/corpora/files/govdocs1/zipfiles

Comment: 3.0.1 of the jbig2 decoder has been released :-) (only one bug, which wasn't about a loop)

Comment: The PDF that takes forever, can you display it at normal resolution with PDFDebugger?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Correction: I'm compiling with jdk 8, but the tomcat where i host runs jvm 7. I have now updated to 2.0.9 and 3.0.1, also added 'setSubsamplingAllowed(true)'. I can neither share nor test the pdf that failed unfortunately since I don't have access to it. I feel like the next step would be to try this new setup & see if it happens again.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr So this happened again, using pdfbox 2.0.9 & Jbig2 3.0.1. The same page got stuck rendering at scale 0.1 multiple times on one of our servers. I tested the file on another server and it works without problem, it also rendered without problem in the pdfbox-debugger.

How dependent is pdfbox on the environment it is running? Could it be because of the jre on the server or missing fonts or something else in the environment?

Comment: I don't really have an idea... however there have been reports on tomcat servlets losing the image decoding library. https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pdfbox-users/201808.mbox/browser